# drupal 7 несколько модулей с одинаковым ключом $items в hook_menu()

Tags: drupal

В Drupal модулю можно задать hook_menu() и вернуть  $items , в котором ключом будет путь url. Вопрос - если в нескольких модулях в hook_menu() одинаковый ключ $items, например $items['user/manager'] - сработают ли все функции 'page callback' ? Просто недавно узнал что срабатывают все модули, если произошло событие на которое они подписаны. Подобно тому как в java-script мы подписываем функцию на какое -то событие.

Comment: В друпал очень нужен дебагер, без него будет сложно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко то ответ - НЕТ, работать будет только один page callback

Посмотри и увидишь сам, я обычно просто дебагер запускаю.

**includes/menu.inc**

```
    /**
 * Collects and alters the menu definitions.
 */
function menu_router_build() {
  // We need to manually call each module so that we can know which module
  // a given item came from.
  $callbacks = array();
  foreach (module_implements('menu') as $module) {
    $router_items = call_user_func($module . '_menu');
    if (isset($router_items) && is_array($router_items)) {
      foreach (array_keys($router_items) as $path) {
        $router_items[$path]['module'] = $module;
      }
      $callbacks = array_merge($callbacks, $router_items);
    }
  }
  // Alter the menu as defined in modules, keys are like user/%user.
  drupal_alter('menu', $callbacks);
  list($menu, $masks) = _menu_router_build($callbacks);
  _menu_router_cache($menu);

  return array($menu, $masks);
}
```

Эта функция возвращает список модулей которые используют этот хук

```
module_implements('menu')
```

Дальше здесь в этой переменной `$callbacks` как видно будут все `$items`. Поскольку используеться array_merge то можно посмотреть на примере как он работает и понять что же будет получено в результате.

```
$items_1['path1'] = array(
    'title' => 'title 1',
    'type' => 2,
    'description' => 'Text',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('form_one'),
    'access arguments' => TRUE,
);

$items_2['path1'] = array(
    'title' => 'title 2',
    'type' => 2,
    'description' => 'Text',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('form_two'),
    'access arguments' => TRUE,
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_merge($items_1, $items_2));
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [path1] => Array
        (
            [title] => title 2
            [type] => 2
            [description] => Text
            [page callback] => drupal_get_form
            [page arguments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_two
                )

            [access arguments] => 1
        )

)
```

Как видно при объявлении двух одинаковых path будет использован второй.